# jquery mobile listview not filling right part of the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview (without icons on the right) and I would like to use the whole list width. I don'tk know how to proceed. I have extra white spaces on the right???

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fPt67/

1st problem: the text of my paragraph is not wrapped in my listview

2nd problem: I did not succeed using the whole list width. There is always white space not used on the right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can play with it till you get it the way you like: http://jsfiddle.net/fPt67/12/

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" style="min-height:100%"> 

        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" > 
        </div> 

        <div data-role="content"> 

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="e" style="white-space:normal"> 
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-e ui-corner-top">Paris</li> 
                <li class="custom_1">
                    <h3>
                    This is a description.
                    </h3>

                    <span class="custom_2">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                    </span>


              </li> 

           </ul> 

        </div> 

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.custom_1 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;  
}

.custom_2 {
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:10px; 
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: There is always some extra space on the right side of the listview as you can see... Don't you have some suggestions to have the text of the paragraph expand on the whole width?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, not only with list styling but other JQM stylings as well. It does not seem to be enough to create your own CSS style--you must overwrite the JQM styles.

Create a .css file which is loaded *after* JQM's css which contains this:

```
.ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li {
padding: .7em 15px .7em 15px;
```

}

This removes the extra padding to the right (75px by default) on listviews as of JQM beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue until I realized that I was using padding in the footer (there's no right space in there for me).

Just removing the footer padding should solve this issue.

Overriding lists styles will remove all spaces from all your lists, btw.